# Why does IIS show me logged in while previous website is already stopped

Tags: iis, webmatrix

I was working on a website that was closed and I started a new project.

The problem here is

1. I logged in to that website while I was using it for testing.
2. I closed that website. And created a new website using WebMatrix.
3. After launching that website, I was still able to see myself logged in.

While there is no data in the Database for the user credentials. You can see this working as

[image]

Here it's shown that the user (my email) is signed in, which was logged in for the previous website. The database for the current user is as

[image]

My question is what is causing this type of issue? Is IIS causing this for the websites by logging the users automatically and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the cookie that gets saved when you log in. It is saved under the domain "localhost". Every site you launch from WebMatrix is in the same domain (just the port number is different) so the cookie is valid for all of them.

Deleting the cookie will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for info :) How can I delete that Cookie? By Simple CTRL + F5? Or do I need to do it at server-side by getting into the IIS application?

Comment: The cookie is stored by the browser. You need to check the documentation for the browser that you are using for instructions on how to delete a single cookie. Each one is different.